# CORS issue with webservice thumbnail.ws

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web-services, cors

I want to write a HTML page who generates a snapshot of an URL using thumbnail.ws free webservice.

Here is my code :

```js
 var myurl = "http://api.thumbnail.ws/api/API_KEY/thumbnail/get?url=http://maps.google.com/?q=36.82,10.17&width=800"
 $.ajax({
            url: myurl,
            crossDomain: true,
            xhrFields: {
         withCredentials: true
      },
            success: function (response) {
                var resp = JSON.parse(response)
                alert(resp.status);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status) {
                alert("error !!!");
            }
        });
```

I have this error in console :

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://api.thumbnail.ws/api/API_KEY/thumbnail/get?url=http://maps.google.com/?q=36.82,10.17&width=800. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

I don't understand why the same URL is working when I paste it in the browser ans even when I write a PHP client using curl, but not when called using AJAX ?

Can I do something or is it a server issue ?

Regards :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try sending your request through an open CORS proxy like https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/:

```
var myurl = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://api.thumbnail.ws/api/API_KEY/thumbnail/get?url=http://maps.google.com/?q=36.82,10.17&width=800"
```

Or else set up your own proxy using the code from https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere/

> I don't understand why the same URL is working when I paste it in the browser and even when I write a PHP client using curl, but not when called using AJAX?

That’s because if you write a PHP client using curl, you don’t run into cross-origin restrictions, and when you paste a URL into the browser address bar, you don’t run into any cross-origin restrictions.

But if you have JavaScript code that’s running on the client side in browser, and it make a cross-origin request using jQuery `$.ajax(…)` or some other library function, or calls XHR/Fetch directly, then that’s outside the same-origin policy that browsers enforce, so by default browsers block it.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS for the details.

The key points to know are that it’s your browser blocking the request, and the only way to get your browser to unblock it is to make the *response* include the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

`http://api.thumbnail.ws` doesn’t seem to send an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, so the only way to make a browser allow your code to work with responses from that is to proxy them through an open service like https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/ or through your own proxy—to add the required `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header  to the response the browser sees.

Comment: Thanks :) I just added this to the ajax calll : headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'},